# How to search changes with `git log` and show the matching lines?

Tags: git

I can use `git log -G search_term` to show the commits in which a line containing string `search_term` was added or removed, but this only shows metadata like the commit message and date, not the actual matching line.

I would like some output like:

```
some_hash: filename.c: + if search_term == True
```

Is this possible with the available options in Git without having to write a shell script?

Answer (score 8):

You could display the full patch along with the log message by using `-p`:

```
git log -G search_term -p
```

Comment: This is the best so far, but if you match in many commits and some of those commits diffs are big it's still hard to see where the matches are. Even if I do the search for the search_term again in `less` output I'm stuck with BRE instead of the ERE offered by `git`.

Comment: maybe `| grep search_term`

Comment: That lacks the essential context: namely, the commit hash and the filename. I suppose I will have to write a script to do this. Thanks for your answer anyway, I didn't know about `-p` :) That's helpful.

Comment: `git log -G search_term -p | egrep '(^commit [0-9a-f]+$)|diff --git|search_term'` will print commit hash and filename too